# Configure limit.conf for ElasticSearch server

Tags: elasticsearch

The ElasticSearch documentation says that I should configure `nofile` and `nproc` for better performance.
But the documentation is a bit confusing.

First, do I configure `nproc` and `nofile` for the "elastic" user that was created by ElasticSearch upon installation or to the `elasticsearch` user (which was not created at all)?

Second, how will the file /etc/security/limits.conf actually look after configuration? Will it look like the code below?

```
elasticsearch    -       nofile       65535
elasticsearch    -       nproc        4096
```

Source:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setting-system-settings.html#ulimit

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setting-system-settings.html#limits.conf